# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException?

Tags: java, facebook, ssl

When I am login with Facebook in my app On local host http://localhost:8080/ its working fine but in client side on Linux environment its throwing this exception : 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
I/O error on POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token":sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if valid certificates are imported in keystore in your Linux environment. I guess it must be in place in your local environment

Comment: In local environment I did not put any certificate but I didn't know from where I will get valid certificates for Facebook in Linux environment.

Comment: Try to import the root cert they ship with the PHP SDK, you can find it here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/master/src/Facebook/HttpClients/certs

Comment: Please tell file location in Linux server I have to paste this file.